# Csv file to MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlet-3.0

Fix the error and i need to import(store) csv files to mysql database table

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection c = null;
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sample", "root", "root");
    Statement s = null;
    s = (Statement) c.createStatement();
    int i = s.executeUpdate("load data local infile 'E:\\Book1.csv' into table sample.copy_table fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n'");
```

Returned errors :

```
Error:Invalid character constant in this line ("load data local infile'E:\\Book1.csv'.......)
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file 'E:Book1.csv'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.FileNotFoundException
MESSAGE: E:Book1.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: ... and what exactly is the problem? Some error message? Data not correctly imported?

Comment: Since you are in Java, I think you should be doing `terminated by '\\r\\n'` and maybe also `'E:\\\\Book.csv'`. That's because the literal you write will be escaped by Java, which will pass it to the SQL server, which will escape it again. If you write `\\B`, the server is receiving `\B`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you forgot to escape `"`:

```
int i = s.executeUpdate("load data local infile 'E:\\Book1.csv' into table sample.copy_table fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\r\n'");
```